# SQL query issue for a tv show table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `tv_series_intervals` (
          `id_tv_series` int(11) NOT NULL,   
          `week_day` smallint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
          `show_time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL)
```

week day in a format 1,2,3,4,5,6,7

show_time it's a converted time to timestamp, for example, `11-45` will convert to `1970-01-01 11:45:00`

How can I get next `id_tv_series` depending on today's datetime?

Does anyone have an idea by what query can I do that?

One example:
TV show (with 1 ID) shows on Wednesday at 00:00 and today is Tuesday 23:59, it should return ID 1

Comment: Can you get the last `id_tv_series` and increase that with 1 ? does it help?

Comment: @sajjadrezaei no, it's a schedule table Next id can be 1 in some cases because for example
TV show (with 1 ID) shows in Wednsday at 00:00 and today is Tuesday 23:59, it should return ID 1

Comment: Aha got it, and you cant store the whole date? Do you just have time? If you store the time as `2021-02-17 11:45:00` process will be easier or just use float field to store the hour and minute. can you change the schema?

Comment: What do you mean by storing the hour and minute? as two separated fields? I can't change database columns but maybe can change a format

Comment: I mean you can store the hour and minute like `11.45` as a float number.

Comment: Yes I can do it

Answer (score 0):

can you change structure to

CREATE TABLE `tv_series_intervals` (
`id_tv_series` int(11) NOT NULL,
`week_day` smallint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
`show_time` TIME NOT NULL)

or perhaps you can include the function to get time sorted by

select *,from_unixtime(show_time, '%h:%i:%s') time from tv_series_interval
order by time

Comment: Yes, I can change the structure like this. what about a day week?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query to achieve your goal.

Assume today is day 1 and the time is `1970-01-01 12:45:00`.

```
(SELECT * from db WHERE show_time > '1970-01-01 12:45:00' AND week_day = 1
ORDER BY show_time LIMIT 1)

UNION ALL
(SELECT * from db WHERE week_day > 1 AND NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * from db WHERE show_time > '1970-01-01 12:45:00' and week_day = 1 ORDER BY show_time LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY week_day , show_time LIMIT 1)

UNION ALL

(SELECT * from db WHERE week_day < 1 and NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * from db WHERE show_time > '1970-01-01 12:45:00' AND week_day = 1 ORDER BY show_time LIMIT 1) AND NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * from db WHERE week_day > 1)
ORDER BY week_day , show_time LIMIT 1)
```

We check if we have the next id today if there wasn't any id today we check for the nearest id on other days.

In the third `select` we check if today is `7` and we have to roll back to `1` and check for the nearest id on day 1.

You can use `float` type instead of timestamp for column `show_time`  that makes sense as well.

If I was you and could modify the backend. I store the next timestamp totally in the database it could reduce the complexity. (e.g. next tv show will be on `18-02-2022 12:10:00`)